# Is there a way to upgrade a windows 2012 r2 vm on Google Cloud Platform to windows 2016 without rebuilding the vm?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, google-cloud-platform

I have a 2012 r2 windows server on Google Cloud Platform.  I would like to upgrade it to 2016 with out a complete rebuild.  Is this possible?

Comment: AFAIK you can't upgrade at all, partly due to licensing. You have to create a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

While it would be technically possible, currently GCP Windows images seems not supporting in-place upgrades. The recommended option would be to create an GCE VM that is running the supported version of the required operating system, and then migrate the workload.

This [reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#operating_system_lifecycle_and_support_policy) can help to understand why this is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't upgrade at all, partly due to licensing. You have to create a new instance